# How can I stream my Linux console output to Youtube?

Tags: linux, console, youtube

I'd like to broadcast a Linux server's console output on Youtube. This console is on a remote machine. I'll be running a trade bot on this particular server and I want my friends to be able see what my bot is doing, live.

I searched for answers but still have no clue where to start.

Comment: please add the info to your post and delete the comment

Comment: I don't think there are any direct solutions. If you can run that bot in a tmux/screen, you can connect to the server from somewhere and reattach to it, then you just need to capture and stream that terminal from the machine you connect from. Another option is to get a device for capturing whatever output the server has.